# Why is a "TeX point" slightly larger than an "American point"?

Tags: tex-history

On p. 58 of *The TeXBook*, Dr. Knuth wrote:

> The units have been defined here so that precise conversion to sp is
> efficient on a wide variety of machines. In order to achieve this,
> TeX's "pt" has been made slightly larger than the official printer's
> point.

According to my calculation, 1 pt in the American Point System is equal to 0.013833...inch. This means that 72.29 pt is equal to 1 inch, while 72.27 TeX pt is equal to 1 inch. As written in the quotation above, the pt in TeX is slightly larger. But how can this difference designed intentionally really work effectively in TeX's internal arithmetic calculation? Could someone explain it?

Comment: Please provide a source to support the claim that "1 pt in the American Point System is equal to 0.013833...inch". For what it's worth, the Wikipedia entry for [Point (typography)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)) has "1 American point = 0.013837in".

Comment: The number is based not on the Johnson Pica, but on TeX's pt.

https://www.cjr.org/language_corner/points-picas-typography-print.php

As the Johnson Pica is equal to 0.166 inch, 1 pt = 0.166 / 12 = 0.013833. . . inch.

Comment: Thanks. It's useful to know that a "Johnson pica" differs slightly from an "American point". :-)

Comment: TeX ises fixed point arithmatic, where 1pt=65536sp (64K), so the real question is why he rounded off 1sp.

Comment: simple: because that 1sp makes it such that you need atleast 24bits (in practice rather 32) to store the 65536 where as 65535 (that what rounding off likely means [down]) is precicely UINT16_MAX

Answer (score 21):

According to the [Wikipedia article on typographic point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)), one point is

0.013837 inches

as defined by the Type Founders Association and this is the value used by Knuth for defining his own slightly different unit. This corresponds to one inch being

72.27000072270000722700... points

so this is why Knuth says that a TeX point is (very) slightly larger than the TFA point. Indeed one TeX point is

.01383700013837000138... inches

From the TeXbook, page 58:

> The units have been defined here so that precise conversion to sp
> is efficient on a wide variety of machines. In order to achieve this,
> TeX’s “pt” has been made slightly larger than the official printer’s
> point, which was defined to equal exactly 0.013837 in by the American
> Typefounders Association in 1886 [cf. National Bureau of Standards
> Circular 570 (1956)]. In fact, one classical point is exactly
> 0.99999999 pt, so the “error” is essentially one part in 10<sup>8</sup>.
>
> This is more than two orders of magnitude less than the amount by which
> the inch itself changed during 1959, when it shrank to 2.54 cm from
> its former value of (1/0.3937) cm; so there is no point in worrying
> about the difference. The new definition 72.27 pt = 1 in is not only
> better for calculation, it is also easier to remember.

About efficiency, we can see it at work in module 458 of `tex.web`:

[image]

Comment: I don't know on what the number 0.013837 based.

Comment: Until the 1950s, the length of an official "American" inch was 25.4000508mm, whereas the length of an official "British" or "imperial" inch was 25.399977mm. Can't we all be grateful that they saw fit to compromise on 25.4mm?! :-)

Comment: @TaroYamamoto It was how the point was defined by the TFA. Why did they choose that value? Probably as a compromise between slightly different definitions used by typographers.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the OP's question though, since they give the same quote. As I understood the question, it's about the part of the quote "so that conversion to sp is efficient on a wide variety of machines": what's the actual relation between the value chosen and efficiency?

Comment: Yes, there used to be a few different deifitnions of "1 American point", though "1 pt = 0.166 inch / 12" was widely known, based on the Johnson Pica used by MacKellar Smiths & Jordan type foundry that was one of the biggest and most influential type foundries in the U.S.

However, what I would like to undestand most is, as Alan Munn wrote, for what reason Dr. Knuth's choice of a "slightly larger" point size became more efficient, and whether or how it was related to the representation format of numbers in TeX (for the unit sp for example) or its arithmetic operations.

Comment: @AlanMunn See edit

Comment: My understanding is that the difference has to do with renormalization groups at energies exceeding 3Tev. It is why so many TeX users create Feynman diagrams. At least, this is as good as any other explanation.

Comment: It is amusing that as consequence of the algorithm shown `72.27pt` turns out to differ from `1in` to TeX. By 1sp.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you for the snapsot image of the page. I will look at the page more closely. This greatly helps me understanding the reason for his selection of the number corresponding to an inch.

Comment: @TaroYamamoto That was egreg's edit, not mine. :)

Comment: *one part in 108.* - I assume that's a copy/paste formatting error, and the original says "one part in 10^8".  In markdown/HTML on Stack Exchange, you can use `10<sup>8</sup>`

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Indeed, it’s the latter that has been used. The other value is what you get for the TFA point.

Comment: @Mico --- Did they also agree on a standardised chain and fathom? What about the barleycorn?

Comment: @IanThompson - You got me on that one. :-) Interestingly, to me at least, in addition to the "American" and "imperial" definitions of an inch (which, I think, go back to at least the 1880s), starting around 1930 there was also something called an "industrial" [!] inch; its length was, you guessed it, exactly 25.4mm. In a way, what's most remarkable is that it took "only" 30 more years for everyone who cares to express lengths in inches, feet, and yards to standardize on this value. (The U.S. adopted the 1in=25.4mm convention in the late 1950s, and the UK followed suit in the early 1960s...)

Comment: @IanThompson Not to mention the difference between “foot” and “survey foot”.

Comment: I understand that 1 pt is equal to 2**16 sp, which requires more than 16 bits.
But in what way is regarding 72.27 pt as 1 inch more efficient than regarding 72.28 or 72.29 pt as 1 inch?

Comment: @TaroYamamoto The choice is not between 72.27 and 72.28, but between 72.27 and 72.2700007227.

Comment: It seems you are talking about the difference between the latest standard in the 1950s and the older 1880s (and 1890s. I know it's very subtle.

Comment: @TaroYamamoto Knuth chose to slightly alter the value of the 1886 point by defining it as 1/72.27 of an inch instead of using that a point is 0.013837in, whatever an inch is. The fact that the inch changed in 1959 is irrelevant about this choice, although it’s handy for making other conversions more efficient numerically.